# C# expandable properties

Tags: c#, properties, expansion

Can I expand properties with complex types to more properties with primitive ones (dynamically (runtime) is also OK)  ?

for example instead of writing this (where the PointExapnder is user defined expansion of some type):

```
class A
{
   public Point Pt
   {
      get;
      set;
   } 

   public int X
   {
      get {return Pt.X;}
      set {Pt.X = value; }
   }

   public int Y
   {
      get {return Pt.Y;}
      set {Pt.Y = value; }
   }

}
```

can I write something like:

```
class A
{
   [Expand(Expander = typeof(PointExpander)]
   public Point Pt
   {
      get;
      set;
   } 

}
```

Comment: What's an `expansion type`? How would the implementation of `PointExpander` look like?

Comment: To what end? How would you use `Pt` any different in the latter case?

Comment: You can use AOP or a Roslyn-based precompiler.

Comment: I have set of tools that needs to be connected (like inMATLAB Simulink). Because every primitive type of some type (e.g. Rectangle needs to be decomposed to X1, Y1, X2, Y2) is input/output parameter of a tool I am looking for a solution to automatically expand those properties (every property is one input / output) to avoid a lot of interfaces. Communication between input/outputs of the tools would be handled through reflection. Or is there a better solution ?